# how call a function with delay of specific time recursively in PHP

Tags: php

I have to call a function recursively for 10 times in every 5 seconds. I have tried sleep function but it didn't work or I implemented it wrong.

Any suggestions how can I implement this?

Comment: Show us your code

Answer (score 1):

I think the first question is. Can you call the function 10 times in 5 seconds?

You could do something like:

```
// return time in seconds
start_time = microtime(true);

while(true) {

    //call function x 10

    // 5 seconds minus the run time of calling the function 10x
    pause_time = 5 - (microtime(true) -  start_time);

   sleep(pause_time); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you make a recursive function and had it sleep for n number of seconds before calling itself again?? And once when you are done with the stuff you can stop it.
Create a variable and store the number of times the function was executed once its 10 don't call the function again.

```php
<?php
function do_stuff(){
  // do something
sleep(2); // wait 2 seconds
//condition to check whatever you were repeating
if(!$condition)
do_stuff(); //call this function again
}
?>
```